# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2:

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm fairly new at coding. In my project, I created a settings menu which should display setting by which the user should be able to search different news stories. The problem I'm having is after clicking on the settingsActivity, my app crashes.

this is my settingsactivity class

```
package com.example.android.newsapp;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.settings_activity);
}

public static class NewsPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment
        implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings_main);

        Preference topicSearch = 
findPreference(getString(R.string.settings_topic_search_key));

        bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(topicSearch);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object 
value) {
        String stringValue = value.toString();
        if (preference instanceof ListPreference) {
            ListPreference listPreference = (ListPreference) 
preference;
            int prefIndex = 
listPreference.findIndexOfValue(stringValue);
            if (prefIndex>= 0) {
                CharSequence[] lables = listPreference.getEntries();
                preference.setSummary(lables[prefIndex]);
            }
        }
        else {
            preference.setSummary(stringValue);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
        SharedPreferences preferences = 
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext());
        String preferenceString = 
preferences.getString(preference.getKey(), "");
        onPreferenceChange(preference, preferenceString);
    }

}
}
```

my settingsactivity xml

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:name="com.example.android.newsapp.SettingsActivity$NewsPreferenceFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/fragment">

</fragment>
```

and the error

```
01-09 22:34:16.602 1899-1899/com.example.android.newsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.newsapp/com.example.android.newsapp.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.android.newsapp.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.android.newsapp.SettingsActivity$NewsPreferenceFragment.bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(SettingsActivity.java:51)
    at com.example.android.newsapp.SettingsActivity$NewsPreferenceFragment.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:30)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:796)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1112)
    at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:4664)
    at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:41)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.android.newsapp.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line from:

```
android:name="com.example.android.newsapp.SettingsActivity$NewsPreferenceFragment"
```

To

```
android:name="com.example.android.newsapp.SettingsActivity.NewsPreferenceFragment"
```

Its probably a long time I have switched from Android , but I think this will work.

Let me know if you are still facing some issues.
Thanks